# Possivelmente, o objeto é 'nulo'.ts(2532) - React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile

Quando vou chamar a função **takePictureAsync** acusa um erro dizendo que **camRef.current.** é **Possivelmente, o objeto é 'nulo'.**, já tentei várias coisas para resolver esse erro mas nenhuma funciona, gostaria de saber o que posso fazer para resolver esse erro.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, CameraType } from 'expo-camera';
import { FontAwesome } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App() {
  const camRef = useRef();
  const [type, setType] = useState(CameraType.back);
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [capturedPhoto, setCapturedPhoto] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const {status} = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
    })();
  }, [])

  if(hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }

  if ( hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>Acesso negado</Text>;
  }

  async function takePicture() {
    if(camRef){
      const data = await camRef.current.takePictureAsync(); // <- AQUI QUE DÁ O ERRO
      setCapturedPhoto(data.uri)
      console.log(data)
    }
  }



  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Camera 
        type={type}
        style={styles.camera}
        ref={camRef}
      >
        <View></View>
        
      </Camera>
      <View style={styles.contentButtons}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.buttonFlip}
            onPress={() => type === CameraType.back ?  setType(CameraType.front) : setType(CameraType.back)}
          >
            <FontAwesome name="exchange" size={23} color='red'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonCamera} onPress={takePicture}>
            <FontAwesome name='camera' size={23} color='white'/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: { 
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%', 
    height: '75%', 
  },
  contentButtons: {
    flex: 0.25,
    backgroundColor: '#292929',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  buttonFlip: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
    left: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    margin: 20,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 50,
    elevation: 10,
  },
  buttonCamera: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50,
    right: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: 20,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    borderRadius: 50,
    elevation: 10,
  }
});
```

Comment: Não seria  talvez `const camRef = useRef(Camera);`?

Comment: Não, ao fazer isso acusa que a propriedade 'takePictureAsync' não existe no tipo 'typeof Camera'.